# Customize a preset so it changed a direction of animation (not reverse it) in After Effects CC

Tags: adobe-after-effects

I'm not an AE expert but I was trying hard to find solution for a few days, so now I decided to ask for help.

I created 3d text animation using standard preset, but I need to change the direction of the effect. I need 2 scenarios:

1. It already fits to my requirements, when the letters start appearing with horizontal flip and in the end we see the whole word.
2. It requires that word is displayed at first and starting to disappear with same effect, but I need the effect starting from first letter.

When I use reverse it's not what I really need, because effect start from the end of the word.

Sources: [gif and ae files](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qlkNERiJxfwjC1Ctf3KPtmrLleJo6LaM)